# What's the Best Rails Gem to use for User Groups?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, usergroups

I want users to be able to create groups and join them. Is there a gem for this already?

Comment: look into `rubygems.org` site.

Answer (score -1):

read up on how to do has_many :through or has_and_belongs_to_many associations in rails